# How to convert AM PM to timestamp for timestampdiff in SQL?

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin, mariadb

I have a generated column that calculates the time difference of time in and time out adding if over time is not empty.

```sql
ALTER TABLE tbl_dtr
  ADD COLUMN total_worked_hours FLOAT(2) AS (CASE 
                                                WHEN time_out = '' then 0
                                                WHEN over_time_out = '' then 0
                                                WHEN time_out <> '' then (TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, time_in, time_out) / 3600)
                                                WHEN over_time_out <> '' then ((TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, time_in, time_out) / 3600) + (TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, over_time_in, over_time_out) / 3600))
                                             END);
```

The problem here the column total_worked_hours will results null, I don't know how to convert AM/PM to timestamp to calculate timestamdiff.

| id | date | time_in | time_out | over_time_in | over_time_out | total_worked_hours |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-08-04 | 08:35 AM | 06:51 PM | 07:05 PM | 11:58 PM | NULL |

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  What is `FLOAT(2)` supposed to be?

Comment: the FLOAT(2) is a type of total_worked_hours that results floating value every row

Answer (score 0):

My "quick and dirty" solution would be:

```
SELECT     
CASE WHEN SUBSTRING('08:35 AM',7,2)= 'AM' 
THEN CONVERT(TIME,SUBSTRING('08:35 AM',1,5)) 
ELSE  DATEADD(HOUR,12,CONVERT(TIME,SUBSTRING('08:35 AM',1,5)) )  END as time
```

Basically

- *substring your time column with format '08:35 AM'*
- *Test if is AM or PM*
- *if AM >>>>   CONVERT(TIME, Substringed value)*
- *else  > >>>> CONVERT(TIME, Substringed value) + 12 hours*

Now you can perform your DATEDIFF operations.

Comment: this shows an error #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(time_in,7,2) = 'AM'
THEN CONVERT(TIME,SUBSTRING(time_in...' at line 2

Comment: I tested and it works on my "ms sql server". MariaDB uses different sinthax for adding date... you should replace DATEADD with DATE_ADD